# redirecting to previous page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect to a previous controller which has an `id` extension, but the function I'm in right now does not contain an `id` extension.
How can I redirect to that page again?  I am giving the data from the controller.

```
public function comment($id, Request $request)
{
    $user_name = $request->session()->get('user_name');
    $ticket = Complaint::Where('id', '=', $id)
        ->SELECT('ticket_no')
        ->get();
    foreach ($ticket as $tickets) {
        $tik = $tickets['ticket_no'];
        $comment = \DB::Select('SELECT comments.comment,comments.comment_by FROM comments JOIN complaints ON complaints.ticket_no=comments.complaint_id Where comments.comment_by=? or comments.comment_by=? AND comments.complaint_id=? ORDER BY comments.id desc limit 2', ["Admin", $user_name, $tik]);

        return view('work.comment', compact('ticket', 'id', 'comment', 'user_name'));
    }
}

public function getComment(Request $request, $id)
{
    $complain_id = $request->input('ticket_no');
    $user_name = $request->input('user_name');
    $comment = $request->input('comment');


    return redirect('ifa-dashboard/comment/', $id);
}
```

This is the route

```
Route::get('ifa-dashboard/comment/{id}','ComplainController@comment')->name('ifa.comment');
Route::POST('ifa-dashboard/getComment','ComplainController@getComment');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the user back to the previous page using the `back()` method. For example:

```php
return redirect()->back();
```